# SQL & Excel 2010

Tags: sql, excel, excel-2010

Good morning,

Does anyone know if there is an easy way I can use a SQL query in Excel to select specific data from an Excel spreadsheet without having to use VBA, Access, an SQL database or complicated Excel formula?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you explain that with an example of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Let's imagine you have a set of cells from which you would like to get some information by executing an SQL query. I would like to know if there is an extension to Excel with which I can put in a cell, for example,

`SELECT TOP 1 (...) FROM A1`

and it would put it that cell the result of the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Microsoft Query.

I don't have Excel 2010 at the mo. In Excel 2007:

Ribbon: Data, From Other Sources (Get External Data From Other Sources), From Microsoft Query, Choose Data Source (dialog), Databases (tab), Excel File* (listbox), Select Workbook (dialog), browse for file, step through Query Wizard (dialog), at finish choose, View or edit query in Microsoft Query, click SQL (toolbar button) and there you can edit the query or change it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

From a program you can use [Jet SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) to query an Excel file.

From within Excel, I don't think you can use Jet SQL.